# Настроить связь с сервером в приложении на c#

Tags: c#, backend

Я новичок в C#

Недавно сделал свой первый проект на нем и хотел бы сделать проверку ключа, при запуске приложения.

Расскажите пожалуйста как настроить связь с сервером и с базой данных так, что бы не было возможности подмены адреса и пакетов.

Заранее благодарю за ответ!

Comment: переведите свой вопрос на понятный язык. А то какие то ключи\пакеты - непоянтно короче. Если вам надо безопасно обмениваться с сервером - используйте SSL

Comment: Подмену пакетов легко - использовать HTTPS, подмену адреса так же, общепринятый способ, у вас весь интернет в браузере так работает. С базой никакой связи у клиента не должно быть, с базой должно работать серверное приложение, а клиентское - с серверным. Вам поможет например сервер на базе например ASP.NET Core Web API.